# SQL SERVER Restore Database with New Columns/PK added?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im adding a new column with primary keys to a database, but there is data within it.
However they want to backup the data and then restore it to the new database with the new column/primary key. When restoring a database is there an option you can select to make sure it doesn't get rid of the new column, and just inserts the database with the new column there (this new column also has a default value as well).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup and restore process will take an exact snapshot of your data and restore it identically. If you want to "merge" two databases then you will need to script both the added columns, tables and data to the production database. There are tools in SQL management studio for this.

re comments

Dropping an index of key will not affect the underlying data. It may block you accessing it while the key is being created (the clustered index is the order the data is stored in the data file). If you want to transfer data between dev and prduction it may be quicker to resore a copy of dev as a spare database on the prod seerver and script an insert between the two databases. Note SQL takes restore seriously and uses all resources to do it as quickly as possible (to the detriment of all other SQL processes) so truncate every table you dont need to transfer data from before backup

The primary key is the index which determins the idenity of each unique row. The custered index determins the order the data is stored and accessed in the file. If you have two rows with the same primary key (which may not be unique) then SQL will add a uniquifying column in the background. SQL will lock the table whist a new clustered index is being implimneted. the underlying data istself will not be changed.

Comment: ?Is there a way to add a new column with a primary key though? everytime I try to add it with a primary key it complains about one already existing. Or is it probably better to rebuild the indexes anyways?

Comment: @Mercfh a table can only have one primary key. You can have a composite primary key but it's still only a single index

Comment: These tables had multiples, I was just adding another composite key to them. But I've been told that it's probably a good idea to backup then restore when adding alot of newer tables with keys.

Comment: @Mercfh then you need to drop and recreate the primary key.

Comment: @Liam thats what I figured, I know you can add columns by altering the table.....but when adding a new Key I was thinking u needed to drop and then recreate the table.

Comment: Yeah I had SQL MNGMT studio script the drop and create. I just didn't know if I HAD to drop it and lose the data, but since im adding a new key...I guess it makes sense i'd have to. Im pretty new to SQL Server so. Thanks all!

Comment: Dropping an index of key will not affect the underlying data. It may block you accessing it while the key is being created (the clustered index is the order the data is stored in the data file). If you want to transfer data between dev and prduction it may be quicker to resore a copy of dev as a spare database on the prod seerver and script an insert between the two databases. Note SQL takes restore seriously and uses all resources to do it as quickly as possible (to the detriment of all other SQL processes) so truncate every table you dont need to transfer data from before backup.

Comment: The primary key is the index which determins the idenity of each unique row. The custered index determins the order the data is stored and accessed in the file. If you have two rows with the same primary key (which may not be unique) then SQL will add a uniquifying column in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore last backup to a new temp Database then use Import menu in management studio to copy your old data to new database.

Check this [link](http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/knowledge-base/?article_id=1187) for more about import data.